# What is MVC architecture?

Tags: software-engineering

I have a programming assignment that says we should use the MVC architecture but we never really learned what that is.

I looked up MVC architecture on google but nothing was helpful. So can someone explain MVC architecture?

Comment: Programming is offtopic here, so I edited these parts away. Also, I don't know how you missed the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC_architecture); *have* you googled? As it stands, you are asking us to reproduce general reference material; that's not what this platform if so. What specifically did you not understand?

Comment: [model view controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) / wikipedia. an OOP design pattern ubiquitous on web that _crosses languages_. think this is on topic here (though basic)

Comment: @Raphael MVC arch. is a standard term -- I don't know why this is marked as unclear. MVC arch's are based on the common MVC design pattern for GUI programs. Each software component (object) is classified as being part of the *Model* or *View* : View objects are those objects that are part of the UI (e.g., buttons, windows, ...); Model objects represent the internal application logic are are view agnostic (e.g., chess engine, database, physics engine, ...); Controller objects are as the mediators between View and Model objects. This decoupling  generally yields a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: @wcochran Did you read my comment? It's unclear what the question is *because* it's a standard term with lots of material on the web already. Would it help you if I closed the question as "too broad" instead?